# How to completely remove a framework from Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I want to remove AdSupport.framework from my project.
I have removed AdSupport from 
Target Project -> General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries

I can still find AdSupport.framework with path using **ack** tool in pbxproj

`$ ack "AdSupport" --ignore-dir="Carthage"`

> Acrostics.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
>   960:        1EDC10831DA3F9FF004706FE /* AdSupport.framework */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = wrapper.framework; name = AdSupport.framework; path = System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework; sourceTree = SDKROOT; };
>   1675:               1EDC10831DA3F9FF004706FE /* AdSupport.framework */,

After an Xcode clean and restart, I can still find the mention of AdSupport in pbxproj.

Why?

Comment: Search your build settings for 'AdSupport'. Probalby `Framework Search Path` or such is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For removing completely, I had to remove from **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** and also from **Project Navigator -> Frameworks**.

Answer (score 0):

***In order to remove frameworks completely from the Xcode project,***

1. Head over to your project.
2. Open Frameworks folder
3. Select the frameworks that you want to remove (hold command key for multiple selection of frameworks)
4. Hold command key and press delete button or drag and drop them to the bin.
5. Click on move to trash button to completely get rid of those frameworks.

***If you want to remove frameworks and replace them with new frameworks,***

1. Go to your project, select your xcode project
2. Select your target on the 2nd left pane, you'll be able to see general tab,
3. Select general tab and scroll down towards the frameworks section,
4. Select the frameworks and click on the minus sign to remove them.
5. This will also remove these frameworks from Build Phases, embed framework and link binary with libraries.
6. Now that you have remove unwanted frameworks, Click on the + sign and add new frameworks. save, clean build, Run and launch your app.